# Nearest Date in a Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
       Date
9.0    2016-03-14
8.0    2016-03-15
7.0    2016-03-16
6.0    2016-03-17
5.0    2016-03-18
4.0    2016-03-21
3.0    2016-03-22
2.0    2016-03-23
1.0    2016-03-24
0.0    2016-03-25
```

I use this code to get the index value of a date:

```
d = df.loc[df["Date"] == "2016-03-21"].index
```

How could be possible for me to get the next possible date's index value if I enter a missing date in a query like below.

```
d = df.loc[df["Date"] == "2016-03-19"].index
```

I need to get "4.0" which belongs to the next possible date 2016-03-21

Comment: This way it seemed easier for me:
    d = df.loc[df["Date"] >= start]
then I get index of first row.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmin`:

```
In [35]: s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])- pd.to_datetime(date)

In [36]: s[s>0].idxmin()
Out[36]: 4.0
```